# Cannot Get status code from xhr response text

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have custom error messages returning from the server and i get it in the **xhr.responseText**.

> {"timestamp":1544419441358,"status":900,"error":"Http Status 900","message":"Origin already exists","path":"/origin/add/"}

I need to get the status code from the above return response. I have tried following way

- xhr.responseText.status

But i cannot get that error 900. What i am getting is undefined.

So how to get the status code from the response text.

Comment: Did you try to `(JSON.parse(xhr.responeseText)).status`?

Comment: please try ```xhr.status``` hope this will work

Comment: Yep as @Mamun said the response is String. That is the problem. xhr.status will return status 500.  but not my custom error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe *responseText* is string, you have to parse the response first:

```
var responseText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
var status = responseText.status;
```

Comment: you are correct. That response is getting as a String. As you said i have converted to JSON object and now everything working fine.